# Understanding what a solution is with an example of the initial value problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

When I have an equation that looks like that:

$$y(t_0) = y_0$$

How do I interpret it?
I have this equation from a text describing the intial value problem where y is the solution to the initial value problem.

But my question really goes to the basics of math. When I have $y_0$, e.g. it is 7, then would the solution, $y$ at $t_0$, also be 7? This is all I can make out of it. But how do I interpret that?

Is there for instance an example where I can make comprehensional sense out of the equation?

Comment: wow, thanks for downvoting!

Answer (score 0):

From what I can gather it seems like you're asking:

If $y(t_0)=y_0$, how do I think about this equation and what relevance does it hold to initial value problems?

So fight off: You could think of dissecting the equation. For simplicity's sake lets assume that $y$ is a function from the reals to the reals. Then the formula you described says that if we take an element $t_0$ from the reals, and inject it in to our function, it will spit out $y_0$.

So if we take some common notation in to a count we may be able to say something significant: $t_0$ usually stands for the time at which you start *"something"* (initial time). Thus, if we take $t_0$ and plug it in to our function $y$, the result is $y_0$.

This means that at the time we start our something, $t_0$ gets mapped to $y_0$ and therefore $y_0$ is the value we get out of $y$ at the very start.

Summary: All that a function $y(t_0)=y_0$ says is that is we take $t_0$ and plug it in to $y$, we get $y_0$. Therefore, if $t_0$ is the initial time of the function, $y_0$ must be the initial value.

Does this answer your questions?